# Why has this abusive comment not been removed

Tags: discussion

[hand analysis](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/10086/hand-analysis-could-you-lay-this-down/10096#10096)

This guy left a comment I need professional mental help.  I flagged it several days ago and it has not been removed.  How is that kind of language OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so from a personal point of view I've been a bit busy with work the last few days so haven't had much time. Apologises for that, as after reading the several comments and tone, completely agree, unacceptable.

I've reviewed and reworded the answer to remove the more aggressive tones from it, let me know if you think there are more, and I've also issued a suspension for the user as all in all, I believe there was 7+ flags against the persons behaviour in this case. Unacceptable, I've been aware of the user's behaviour in the past, several comments directed against me, but this was excessive. Hope this clears things up and again apologises for slowness.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  That guy is just really aggressive in every post.

Comment: Well dealt with Grinch.